# Proof that $\left(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{y}\right)$ is a convex region if $(x, y)$ is

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm trying to convince (prove) myself that if a set $S \subset \mathbb{({R^+})^2}$ is a convex region, then $S' := \left\{ \left(\frac1{x}, \frac1{y}\right) ; (x, y)\in S \right\}$ is also a convex region. I've tried using the definition of convexity, and the couple of convexity-preserving transformations (linear, affine, etc.) but I still can't establish my claim. Is my claim even true?

The closest I've gotten to show this is that $(x,y) \text{ is convex} \implies (x,y,1) \text{ is convex} \implies \left (1, \frac{y}{x}, \frac{1}{x}\right) \text{ is convex (perspective transform)} \implies \left (\frac1x, \frac{y}{x}\right) \text{ is convex}$

Here by $(x, y)$ I am abusing notation to refer to the set $S$.

PS: For the problem I'm actually trying to solve, $S$ is the interior of an ellipse, so even if my claim isn't true for general $S$, could it be true for this particular case?

Comment: An inequality which can be useful (a version of the fact than Arithmetical Mean larger the Harmonic Mean) $\frac{1/x+1/y}{2} \ge \frac{1}{(\tfrac{x+y}{2})}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true, not even for an ellipse. A line segment (and hence, a sufficiently thin ellipse) may be warped by the transformation, see example picture below.

[image]

Comment: Though it might still be true for circles

Comment: I think you should swap the red and the blue dot on the straight line, no? $(3,1)$ gets mapped to $( 1/3, 1).$

Comment: Whoops, oh well

Comment: A great answer. Now, I checked for the circle $(1.5, 1.5) + (\cos t, \sin t)$ and the image is visibly concave. [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B+%7B1%2F%28Cos%5Bt%5D+%2B+1.5%29%2C+1%2F%28Sin%5Bt%5D%2B1.5%29%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C0%2C2Pi%7D%5D)

Comment: Great counter-example, thanks!